# Como pegar o caminho do arquivo de upload do usuário em javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estou criando uma página web com um iframe, e gostaria de mudar o src desse iframe para o caminho de upload do usuário, gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso, segue código:

```
<input type="file">
<div class="framePDF">
    <iframe id="frames" style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 650px"  src="Desenvolvimento WEB com HTML, CSS e JavaScript.pdf;embedded=true" frameBorder=0;></iframe>
</div>
```

Meu código iframe está fixo, mas gostaria de mudar ele conforme o usuário escolhe o arquivo

Comment: Você quer exibir o arquivo local do cliente?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso...

Comment: não é possível, vai aparecer como fakepath

Comment: Na verdade a sua pergunta não faz muito sentido... você quer exibir no browser um arquivo que está na máquina do cliente ao invés de fazer o upload?

Answer (score 0):

Galera, consegui resolver o problema, eu precisava criar um input do tipo file, e fazer um código script com FileReader, assim ele lê o arquivo e apresenta

```
<input type='file' accept='file/*' onchange='openFile(event)'>

<div id="framePDF" class="framePDF" style="display: none">
        <br>
        <iframe id="frame" style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 650px" frameBorder=0;></iframe>
        <!--O Comando iFrame permite criar um frame na página web para a leitura de um arquivo PDF -->
    </div>

    <script>
        var openFile = function(event) {
            var input = event.target;

            document.getElementById('framePDF').style.display = 'block';

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function() {
                var dataURL = reader.result;
                var output = document.getElementById('frame');
                output.src = dataURL;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        };
    </script>
```

Agradeço pela ajuda... Com esse código, ele cria um iframe, o usuário escolhe um arquivo da própria maquina, o script processa ele, lê, e coloca as informações dentro do iframe